# Make Google Assistant open my app on a specific state

Tags: android, actions-on-google

I am trying to integrate my android app with google assistant. I've already done some research and went through some tutorials, but they only bring me text, card, or audio responses. What I need is that the google assistant open my app on a specific state based on what it is asked to google assistant.

For example, I will ask google assistant when will the next game of my favorite team happen. Then google assistant will open my app showing the schedule of the next games of my favorite team. I think it might be possible to do it with webhooks, but I don't know how. Can someone link me some references to help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will want to sign up for the [app actions](https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/) developer preview, which will expose intents in your app to be opened from the Assistant.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It helped a lot!

Comment: How can I open my Foo app if user commands something that my app is capable of handling? Do I have to define actions for that?

Comment: You'll need to check out the documentation once the app actions preview is open.

Comment: The use cases that Google offers for these actions are useless for most cases.