# Calling Android app API through Google Assistant custom action

Tags: android, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

In my application, I need to use Google Assistant to ask custom questions to a user that has already logged in. Based on the user input, I need to make an API call and place an entry for the user. I can use any Google Assistant supported devices to call my API.

Google Assistant allows me to create custom actions and from the fulfillment I can see that there is an option to call the API.

My question is: How can I make an entry for the particular user in the database via API calls? What is the correct way to accomplish this? I am wondering if this can be accomplished with Google Assistant or if I will require Google Voice Actions.

Google Assistant seems to provide all the options to satisfy my requirement. However, I am unsure how to put an entry against the particular user logged into my android application from my device via API call.

Any insight to this is helpful, thank you!

Comment: This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51182446/make-google-assistant-open-my-app-on-a-specific-state/51199263#51199263

Comment: Thanks for your response. I saw about Actions, Google Actions SDK, Dialogflow and all. My questions to how to maintain the action response against specific users. I got answer when I surfed on this we have something called oAuth which I can use for this purpose

Comment: https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking

Comment: The App Actions are the only way to directly do logic between an Android app and an action.

Comment: i have similar requirement. any success doing it?

Comment: Yes you can use DialogFlow and handle API calling, oauth everything with the nodejs code backend. It' fully doable over there no need any mobile logic code. This is how we done now. If you have any more useful solutions please post